# How to Design a WPF Flow Document

Tags: wpf, xaml, designer, blend, flowdocument

Im making an wpf application and i need to generate reports and then to print them. I am using [CodeReason.Reports](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70128/Open-Source-WPF-Reporting-Engine) library but it is very dificult to me to design the reports with out a designer.

Any one knows if there exist any Flow Document designer, or if there is any way to design it from blend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the library you are talking about, but I used WPF for creating some report, let's say a minimal report engine, so I think I can give some suggestion to you. 
First, learn XAML. Visual studio has a good designer, but I use it just to see  what's happening: writing XAML with the good Visual Studio intellisense is much more productive. I can't suggest how to operate with your lib, but with my strategy the document pages are wired by the engine in code, content are produced by user controls: they just live very well in VS designer. I also used an MVVM library to develop in a an code free view way.
So what I learn in y WPF experience: it is a great and powerful environment, you can present thing the way you want, but don't look for a cutting edge designer. The WPF designer is XAML, mastering it is necessary.

Comment: I'm agree with you in all topics you are talking about, but some times you need to generate fast solution, and it is very problematic compile, then run your application for to see the design changes, then change the code and recompile againg,...

Answer (score 1):

I used flow documents in a regex tool I created. I ended up creating a programmatic wrapper over the flow document library which once done was easy to use because it had my target look and feel.

No, AFAIK there is no design tool for flow documents nor does Blend support it. Create a document and provide a wrapper which speaks to that design is your best option if you use flow documents.

Comment: I doesn't understand very well what do you means.